# Qual é a melhor apresentação para o título: "Apuração de Falhas Administrativas/Técnicas dos Funcionários"?

Tags: concordância-nominal, acordo-ortográfico, adjetivos

Estou revisando a tradução de uma aplicação para o português, e um dos títulos sugeridos pelo tradutor é:

> "Apuração de Falhas Administrativas/Técnicas dos Funcionários"

Este título soa-me estranho, mas não consigo apontar onde na norma culta ele falha.

Pensei em algumas alternativas, como as abaixo:

> Apuração de Falhas Administrativas ou Técnicas dos Funcionários

ou

> Apuração de Falhas, Administrativas ou Técnicas, dos Funcionários

O sentido da frase é que serão apuradas falhas atribuidas aos funcionários, e estas falhas podem ser de natureza técnica ou administrativa. Preciso escolher a apresentação que melhor transmita este sentido.

Quais são as regras da norma culta da língua portuguesa para a formação desta frase?

Dentro da norma culta da língua portuguesa (novo acordo ortográfico), qual a melhor apresentação para este título?

Comment: Eu preferiria "Levantamento de falhas dos funcionários (Administrativas/Técnicas)"

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo grandes problemas com a frase original, parece-me bem fácil de compreender. A barra (`/`) é geralmente entendida já como «ou». Até acho que subtituir a barra por «ou» prejudica o título, porque podemos lê-lo como «Apuração de Falhas Administrativas e [Técnicas dos Funcionários]», já que «técnicas» também funciona como nome.

Se quiseres ser mais explícito podes escrever (troquei também a ordem de «técnica» e «administrativa» — é mais comum ocorrerem com «técnica» primeiro):

> Apuração de Falhas de Natureza Técnica ou Administrativa Atribuíveis aos Funcionários

mas não me parece que se ganhe muito com isso.